# Why does rollup throw "Must use import to load ES Module"?

Tags: rollupjs

I have the following code that works fine with rollup...

```
// rollup.config.js
import pkg from './package.json';

export default [{
  input: pkg.src,
  external: ['ms'],
  output: [
    {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'esm'
    }
  ]
}];
```

I created a project to make simple UMD, CJS and ESM so now I want to make the code...

```
import { getMJS } from "@jrg/build"

import pkg from './package.json';

export default [
  getMJS(pkg)
];
```

But when I try to run this I get...

```
[!] Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /.../web-components/packages/base/node_modules/@jrg/build/dist/index.mjs
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /.../web-components/packages/base/node_modules/@jrg/build/dist/index.mjs
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1048:11)
```

What am I missing? The index.mjs file in @jrg/build is...

```
// node_modules/@jrg/index.mjs
import { string } from 'rollup-plugin-string';

const myString = string({
  include: "**/*.(html|css|svg)"
})

const getMJS = function(pkg, plugins){
  plugins = plugins || [ ];
  plugins.push(myString);
  return {
    input: pkg.src,
    plugins: plugins,
    external: ['ms'],
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'esm'
      }
    ]
  }
};
export { getMJS };
```

**UPDATE**

So it does work if I use the CJS version like this...

```
import * as build from "@jrg/build/dist/index.cjs"

export default [build.getMJS(pkg)];
```

But if I try changing to `rollup.config.mjs` and running `rollup -c rollup.config.mjs` I get...

```
[!] TypeError: defaultLoader is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Using relative pathing worked for me like...

```
import {getMJS, getUMD} from "../../node_modules/@jrg-material/build/dist/index.mjs"
```